# How to add mouseDoubleClick event for each label in SWT Tree via TreeViewer's providers?

Tags: java, events, tree, swt, listener

I have a Tree generated with a help of TreeViewer. I need to add items from this tree to another component, when user double clicks it with mouse. I suppose that mouseListener has to be added for each label in the tree. But I wonder how to add mouseDoubleClick event listeners via TreeViever's providers. I've already implemented content and label providers, but I don't see any interfaces, which I can use for getting generated labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a single double click listener to the `TreeViewer` with the `addDoubleClickListener` method. The parameter is a class that implements `IDoubleClickListener`:

```
treeViewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void doubleClick(final DoubleClickEvent event)
    {
      final IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection)event.getSelection();

       // TODO deal with the selection
    }    
});
```

The `DoubleClickEvent` parameter contains the information about the selected object in the tree.